# Why does twist distribute itself according to the thickness of yarn?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, torque, elasticity

In spinning, a convenient physical reaction happens when you haven't drafted (pulled the fibres apart) enough to make a consistent gauge of yarn. Thinner spots will accumulate more twist, while the twist "jumps" over wider spots allowing them to be drafted easier (you don't want the thin spots any thinner, but the twist holds them together while there is less twist in thicker spots). What is responsible for this distribution of twist?